# Script to check if a backup ran

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that checks folders to see if a backup has run for that particular installation.I have a number of folders and in these folders are the backup .zip files, the names of the files are the same for all folders so for example folder A has the file "Backup.zip" folder B will also have "Backup.zip" but from a different installation. At the moment I got it working fine but it's not looking very good and for example if a new folder gets created and a backup will be placed here I need to copy paste a whole block of text in the script and change the names. I'm looking for a more automated check that if I add a folder it will check that aswell.
Also the point of the checks is , if the file didn't change (or is not present at all) in the last 24 hours I should be notified by e-mail, which I also have working right now.

This is the code I have right now

```
if (Test-Path "<Path to file>") 
{
   if ( ((get-date) - (ls <Path to file>).LastWriteTime).days -lt 1)
      {  
        $success++
      }
  else
      {
    Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject "!!Backup failed!!" -Body "!!Backup failed!!" -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential -UseSsl
    $failed++
     }
}
else
{
    Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject "!!Backup not found!!" -Body "!!Backup not found!!"  -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential -UseSsl
    $failed++
}
```

The variables $success and $failed is just used for a general email that gets sent after it has ran all the checks to see how many ran successfull and how many failed.

But this code above is what I have to copy everytime a new folder for backups is created, so I manually have to edit the Path to file aswell. Can somebody help me or push me in the right direction to make it an automated thing? I'm extremely new to Powershell and I don't really know how to get it going. I do know there is a thing called 'foreach' but I have no clue how to implement it here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I managed to get it working partly, for some reason about 8 folders can't get checked, I get this error on those folders. 37 other folders get checked fine, what can be the issue here? All the folders have the same properties.

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IO.FileInfo".
At line:25 char:6
+ if ( ([System.Io.fileinfo] $i).LastWriteTime.Date -ge [datetime]::Tod ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Answer (score 0):

the code it will be like that

```
#if there is more than one parent path mentioned all of them in array like $parents = "path1","path2", ..... and loop on them with the same foreach
$Parentpath = <Parent path which contain the backups>

foreach ($folder in $parentpath){
        #check it is a folder not a file
        if (($Folder.GetType().name) -eq "DirectoryInfo"){

          $path = Convert-Path $folder.PSPath
          }

        if (Test-Path "$path") 
        {
           if ( ((get-date) - (ls if (Test-Path "$path") ).LastWriteTime).days -lt 1)
              {  
                $success++
              }
          else
              {
            Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject "!!Backup failed!!" -Body "!!Backup failed!!" -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential -UseSsl
            $failed++
             }
        }
        else
        {
            Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject "!!Backup not found!!" -Body "!!Backup not found!!"  -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential -UseSsl
            $failed++
        }
}
```

Comment: Currently when trying out the code only the last folder gets checked, I don't need to check if its actually a folder since there are only folders in the parent path. This is what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $Parentpath = "\\x.x.x.x\FTPbackups\3CX\"

foreach ($i in $parentpath)
{

if ( ([System.Io.fileinfo] $i).LastWriteTime.Date -ge [datetime]::Today )
    {     
  
    Write-Host "-=File Found for '$i'"

    $success++
    }
else
    {

    Write-Host "-=File found but not modified in the last 24 hours"

    Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject "!!Backup van niet gelukt!!" -Body "!!Backup van niet gelukt!!" -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential -UseSsl
    $failed++
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand how it works, do I need to make an array with every path of every folder?